# Create function/procedure to return table to get the last rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, max

I have several tables, each with a different key.

For example: the key for the `Customer` could be 2 or more columns.

Input - dbo.customer:

```
Customer e_Date    Value
------------------------
1000     2019-05-26  200
1000     2019-05-25  100
2000     2019-04-23   50
2000     2019-04-21   20
```

Output :

```
Customer  e_date       value
----------------------------
1000      2019-05-26    200
2000      2019-04-23     50
```

The max dates and the values for them was return for each customer (key).

I want to build a function or procedure in SQL where I will enter the name of table and the key and will return me the output. A return table function.

```
exec procedure get_Last_Row_By_Key (@Table_Name, @Key)
```

and it will show me the output.

In this example :

```
exec procedure get_Last_Row_By_Key ('dbo.customer', Customer)
```

I guess that when the `@key` will be multiple value I can do concat of the other columns to make them a one column key.

Comment: You need dynamic sql  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: All other table has same e_Date & Value in them? And what if Maximum e_Date & Value belongs to different row? Or you need the e_Date where the Value is Maximum?

Answer (score 0):

put below query in your function using `row_number()` window function

```
 select customer,e_date,value from 
           (select *,row_number()over(partition by customer order by e_date desc) rn
 from table ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call would need to be something like this:

```
exec procedure get_Last_Row_By_Key ('dbo.customer', 'Customer', 'e_date')
```

To support multiple keys, I would use `row_number()`, even though that adds an extra column to the result set.  So the dynamic SQL would look like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [key] order by [datecol]) as seqnum
      from [table] t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[table]', @table);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '[key]', @key);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '[datecol]', @datecol);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note:  I am explicitly *not* using `quotename()` here, so the code will allow multiple columns for either the key order "datecol".

Also, as an exercise, this might be useful for learning about dynamic SQL and stored procedures.  In general though, such attempts at "generic" processing are not as useful as they seem.  People who know SQL know how to write the query to do what they want on a table; they do not know custom stored procedures that do the same thing.